# @DBCommand and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I've been using @DBCommand on MySQL db's. Great success. Now I have to switch to SQL Server.

1. I manage to update the SQL Server database just fine (via Domino).
2. The problem occur when I try to generate a report for the web user (Domino). 
   The query works like a charm in SQL Server Management Studio. Running the web page yields:

> *Data Access Application Layer>Could not execute @db function*

The original query worked just fine against MYSQL.

**I am in need of some resources/documentation/web page describing hints and tips in order to make it work. Any ideas?**

Example query that fails (when using Domino):

```
  SELECT COUNT( bruk_NR ) as [antall], [brukere_Navn], [bruk_NR]
  FROM [stat].[dbo].[bruk]
  INNER JOIN
  [stat].[dbo].[brukere] 
  ON bruk.bruk_NR = brukere.brukere_NR AND bruk.bruk_NR = brukere.brukere_NR
  GROUP BY bruk.bruk_NR, brukere.brukere_Navn, brukere.brukere_brukerID
  ORDER BY [brukere_brukerID] ASC
```

Thanks in advance 
Hal.

Comment: It looks like I sorted it out by making a stored procedure. Only challenge is that I see only one column of data when retrieving the result. The following colums are lost (2,3,4)

Comment: You can concatenate the columns together in the SQL, then parse them out on the Notes side.